# Firebug shortcut {Ctrl + Shift + C} toggles Firefox Developer Tools instead of Firebug Inspect Element

Tags: firefox, firebug, shortcut, inspector

Since Firefox updated itself to version 28 (running on Windows 7), I can not get the Firebug shortcut for element inspection to work (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>). When I press this key combination, the default Developer Tools window pops up. In earlier versions of Firefox this problem could be tackled by simply unchecking/disabling the Inspector tool in the settings of Firefox' Development Tools. However, this checkbox is no longer there:

[image]

I tried the following:

- Reinstalled Firefox and Firebug.
- In `about:config`, I searched for `devtools.*.enabled`, and set all values to `false`.
- I downloaded an addon called *Customizable Shortcuts*, but changing any of the shortcuts did not solve my problem, the new shortcuts do not get recognized.
- In the default Firebug Shortcut Bindings window, changing any of the shortcuts does not affect anything, similarly, the new shortcuts do not get recognized.

Even when I bind the Firebug inspector to a shortcut that isn't in use (i.e., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>) it still does not get recognized:

[image: Firebug Shortcut Bindings dialog]

It looks like Firebug is prevented from assigning any key combination, or maybe there something else going on.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that in [issue 6991](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6991), which is included in [Firebug 2.0 alpha 1](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2014/03/26/firebug-2-0-alpha-1/). Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Still not working as it should be, i bound Ctrl + Shift + C to the Firebug inspect tool. Sometimes it works as intended and Firebug pops up, but in some cases the default Firefox Developer Tools window pops up again. I can't really find out when it occurs and when it doesn't.. it looks kinda random.

As a temporary solution, I downgraded to Firefox version 27, in which everything works fine. Not an ideal solution though :(

Comment: Forgot to mention that 2.0a1 requires Firefox Aurora (30.0a2) or higher. As a workaround you can set the shortcut to Ctrl+Alt+Shift+C for now. That's at least working for me.

Comment: I know, I was testing it on Nightly 31.0a1. Thanks for the workaround, but hopefully it will be fixed in the future! ;)

Comment: Note that it works fine for me (on Win7) when I reset the shortcut with the "reset" button on the right side within the _Firebug Shortcut Bindings_ dialog. If you have clear steps how to reproduce the problem, please report it at the [Firebug issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/entry), so it can be fixed.